# Sum over pandas dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a Pandas dataframe on this format

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"i": [1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   "k": [2,3,1,3,4,5,6],
                   "X_ik": [4,0,1,14,2,12,5]})
display(df)
```

```
    i   k   X_ik
0   1   2   4
1   1   3   0
2   2   1   1
3   2   3   14
4   3   4   2
5   3   5   12
6   3   6   5
```

For each row, which corresponds to a unique pair of `(i,k)`, I want to sum all `X_ik` where

1. `k` equals to current `i` of `(i,k)`,
2. `i` does not equal to current `k` of `(i,k)`.

If no values are available for summation, then it's simply `0`.

Illustrative example:

```
(i,k) sum              explanation
(1,2): 0               sum all X_i1, but X_21 (if it exists)    
(1,3): 1               sum all X_i1, but X_31 (if it exists)   
(2,1): 0               sum all X_i2, but X_12 (if it exists)
(2,3): 4               sum all X_i2, but X_32 (if it exists)
(3,4): 0+14            sum all X_i3, but X_43 (if it exists) 
(3,5): 0+14            sum all X_i3, but X_53 (if it exists)
(3,6): 0+14            sum all X_i3, but X_63 (if it exists)
```

I can perform the sum without the second condition using vectorized operations as

```
s = df.groupby('k')['X_ik'].sum()
df['sum'] = df['i'].map(s)
display(df)
```

```
    i   j   X_ik sum
0   1   2   4    1
1   1   3   0    1
2   2   1   1    4
3   2   3   14   4
4   3   4   2    14
5   3   5   12   14
6   3   6   5    14
```

but then the first row `(1,2)` and third row `(2,1)` are wrong, since they sum too many values by not taking the second condition into account.

I'm mainly looking for a solution using vectorized operations since the df will be large in practice, but all solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vectorial approach, you can fix your sum by removing the extra items with a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
s = df.groupby('k')['X_ik'].sum()

diff = (df[['i', 'k']].reset_index()
        .merge(df.rename(columns={'i': 'k', 'k': 'i'}))
        .groupby('index')['X_ik'].sum()
        .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
       )

df['sum'] = df['i'].map(s).sub(diff, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   i  k  X_ik  sum
0  1  2     4    0
1  1  3     0    1
2  2  1     1    0
3  2  3    14    4
4  3  4     2   14
5  3  5    12   14
6  3  6     5   14
```

Intermediate `diff`:

```
0    1
1    0
2    4
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
Name: X_ik, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use numpy broadcasting with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and `sum`:

```
k = df['k'].to_numpy()
i = df['i'].to_numpy()

df['sum'] = np.where((k == i[:, None]) & (i != k[:, None]), df['X_ik'], 0).sum(axis=1)
print(df)

   i  k  X_ik  sum
0  1  2     4    0
1  1  3     0    1
2  2  1     1    0
3  2  3    14    4
4  3  4     2   14
5  3  5    12   14
6  3  6     5   14
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
df['sum'] = [df.loc[df['k'].eq(i) & df['i'].ne(k), 'X_ik'].sum() 
             for k, i in zip(df['k'], df['i'])]
```

Comment: @Nick maybe not with a real dataset, broadcasting generates all combinations `O(n²)`, most of which are useless here. For a large dataframe you might not even fit in memory and might end up computing 99% of useless things.

Comment: @mozway good point. Probably still true for the list comprehension but I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.. We apply a function that fits your criteria row wise

```py
def custom_sum(row, df):
    return df[(df['k'] == row['i']) & (df['i'] != row['k'])]['X_ik'].sum()

df['sum'] = df.apply(custom_sum, df = df, axis = 1)
```

Comment: It works good for small dataframes, but takes way to long when number of rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by making a few small changes.

```
s = df.groupby('k')['X_ik'].sum()
s1 = df[['i', 'k']].merge(df.set_axis(['k', 'i', 'X_ik'], axis=1), how='left')['X_ik']
df['sum'] = df['i'].map(s) - s1.fillna(0)
```